# Is Scapy included in Anaconda?

Tags: python, visual-studio, anaconda

I am new to Python, and for a computer networks project I need to use a protocol package called Scapy. I have already downloaded Anaconda, and I know it has a huge package library. How can I know whether I already have Scapy in my computer installed? How do I check (Ubuntu) if I have a certain package before downloading it again?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen on the packages list [Scapy (v2.2) is available on Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/scapy) for Linux and OSX. As mentioned it can be installed using the following command (from the command/terminal window):

```
conda install -c conda-forge scapy
```

It would not have been installed as default. You can see what is installed in your Anaconda installation like this:

```
conda list
```

You can also do the above using the `Anaconda Navigator` app by going to the Environments tab.

If you want install packages that aren't available through conda then you can do it, but you'll need to follow the conda manual pages on [package management](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I know whether I already have Scapy in my computer installed?

If you did not install it, then it isn't installed, you need to install
it.

> To install scrapy on Ubuntu (or Ubuntu-based) systems, you need to
> install these dependencies:
>
> sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
> zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
>
> - python-dev, zlib1g-dev, libxml2-dev and libxslt1-dev are required for lxml
> - libssl-dev and libffi-dev are required for cryptography
>
> If you want to install scrapy on Python 3, you’ll also need Python 3 development headers:
>
> sudo apt-get install python3 python3-dev
>
> Inside a virtualenv, you can
> install Scrapy with pip after that:
>
> pip install scrapy

[Ubuntu 14.04 or above](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html)